# How to get a node by id?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have the following xml format

```
<locale id='us'>
items here
</locale>
```

How do I get the locale node by its id?

I have the following codes

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("config.xml");
$nodes = $xml->xpath('*[id = "us"]');
```

but i guess it's not the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@` axis specifier to refer to an attribute:

```
*[@id='us']
```

If you want to get an element by ID that can appear anywhere in the document, then use:

```
//*[@id='us']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("config.xml");
$nodes = $xml->xpath("*[@id='us']");
```